# Did Darth Vader modify his TIE Advanced x1?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, spaceship, darth-vader

One of the few traits of Anakin Skywalker that Darth Vader retained and continued to embrace is his habit of tinkering with machines in his free time. He is known to have done so with his body suit.

Has Vader ever done the same with his personal TIE Advanced x1? If so, what are some of the customisations he made?

Comment: I felt my answer to this one was reasonably solid, featuring panels from the only extant factbook that directly addresses the *in-universe source* of the modifications to his X1. Is there anything else you'd want me to address before considering an acceptance?

Answer (score 8):

Vader doesn't appear to have customised his TIE-Advanced X1 fighter *personally*. He seems to have left the heavy lifting to Sienar Systems, the company tasked with providing TIE-Fighters to the Empire.

What we do know is that he selected a top-of-the-line *prototype* model for himself. This prototype has a more robust chassis, improved targeting capabilities and an "augmented engine assembly" that makes it faster and more maneuverable than an ordinary TIE/Ln. Additionally he asked them to customise the seating to accomodate his life-support and larger frame.

There are also some other things (deflector shields, hyperdrive system) that you wouldn't normally find in a fighter craft due to the extra weight.

[image]
[image]
[image]

<sub><sup>Images from [Star Wars: Incredible Cross-Sections](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Incredible_Cross-Sections)</sup></sub>